# live Agent chat window not popping up

Tags: liveagent

When receiving chats, the case is automatically created in SFDC but my chat\reply window (see screenshot live agent 4) does not pop up any more…(crashes)? 
see screenshots attached, same in IE and Google chrome

Then, I can only close the case (which closes the chat), reopen the case (chat transcript is auto-attached to case) and reply via email.

Happens since a couple of days, first not frequently, now for every chat case received
pls advise
[image: live agent error 1]

[image: live agent 4]

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you have another Salesforce app open. Not sure why, but you can't open Live agent console app and any other App in your org at the same time. This is a real pain.

Make sure you close the rest of the apps, logout and login again. 
Open the app in another browser or incognito mode doesn't resolve the issue (I've already tried)

I've been looking for a solution, and there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The chat column is simply collapsed. If you hover over the border between your two columns, just left of the word "File", you'll see a triangle you can click to expand the chat back out.